# Excel ExportAsFixedFormat Breaks Loop Specific iterations

Tags: excel, vba, loops, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to use a UserForm to choose a list of names to export as a PDF into a specific file. This has worked previously for me, but it is now stopping the loop and causing errors, but it's only for specific names that don't work to export. When I get the invalid procedure call or argument error it points to the ExportAsFixedFormat section as the error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the Export Code

```
    Public Sub ExportPDF(whichSheet As Worksheet, which_BusinessLine As String)
'
' ExportPDF Macro
'

Dim OutputPath As String
Dim OutputFileName As String
OutputPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\CG\BS-Materials\BS\Completed\BS - 6.3.2020"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
OutputFileName = OutputPath & Application.PathSeparator & which_BusinessLine & "- BS - 6.3.2020.pdf"
whichSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=OutputFileName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

And here's the code from the user form that is calling the export function

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
If ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim lastprintrow As Long

Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("OfficeDashboard")
Set mySheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Journal Breakdown")
Sheets("Offices").Range("Z2:Z500").ClearContents 'delete the previous print list from the control panel page (Print list is in Z2-Z500)


'Loop through the selected business lines and paste them into export list column on the Offices Sheet (Z)
For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    Sheets("Offices").Cells(2 + i, 26) = ListBox2.List(i) '2+i rows down 26 columns over (column Z) on Offices sheet for export list
Next i

Unload Me  'empty the form and close it

Sheets("Offices").Select
'If the export list in column Z exceeds the 500 in the Cells formula you need to increase that number
lastprintrow = Cells(500, 26).End(xlUp).Row 'find out how many sheets need to be exported by looking at bottom of the Offices list going up (500 rows down, 26th column)

For j = 2 To lastprintrow   'for each row down from 2 until you find the end of the export list (J=2 means 2nd row down is where list begins)
mySheet.Range("C3") = Sheets("Offices").Cells(j, 26).Value 'copy the name to the program page drop list (Cell B5) j,2=which column print list name is
mySheet2.Range("C3") = Sheets("Offices").Cells(j, 26).Value
Application.Calculate 'make sure that the formulas recalculate
ExportPDF whichSheet:=mySheet, which_BusinessLine:=Trim(mySheet.Range("C3").Value)

Next j 'move to the next name on the list

Set mySheet = Nothing

MsgBox "All Snapshots Exported"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `which_BusinessLine` when it fails? Seems like an issue with the filename.

Comment: It's the same as any other value in the array. Just a text value from whatever was chosen in the userform and then printed onto mySheet.Range(C3). Everything in the array is the same in terms of format, it just works for some and not others

Comment: A sample value would be helpful...

Comment: The array would be something like this: {ABC Office;Boyle Office;Bridge Office;Chessman Office;Concierge Office} and I would select all and it would break on the Chessman one

Comment: The only thing changing in your `ExportAsFixedFormat` call is the `OutputFileName` - highly suggest you `Debug.Print` it... something is causing it to fail.

Comment: I have tried using `Debug.Print` for `which_BusinessLine` and `whichSheet.Name` and it's showing me the values that it should be

Comment: What are the actual values passed to the `ExportAsFixedFormat ` when the function fails?

Comment: How do I see what those values are?